# JavaFX Combo into TableView with database data

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I want to insert a `ComboBox` into a Cell (`TableView`).
I took data from Mysql.
You can see the database schema in the picture:

[image: database]

How can I put data into a `ComboBox` and insert that `ComboBox` into a `TableView`? 
 I have succeeded to get a company name but I have failed to create and put the name into a `ComboBox` in a `TableView`.

Here is the java code:

```
public class Controller { 
    private ViewCompany viewCompany;
    @FXML
    private TableView<ViewCompany> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ViewCompany, String> companyColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ViewCompany, ObservableList<BankAccount>> accountColumn;


    /**
     * This is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp() {
        viewCompany = ViewCompany.getInstance();
    //ViewCompany.obt() => Get data
        table.setItems(viewCompany.obt());
    }


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        companyColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCompany().getName());

    //How do I initialize a ComboBox with multiple bank accounts?
    //How do I insert the ComboBox into a TableView?
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to repeat all bank accounts with combo boxes informing what company X has from them ?

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3QmRr.jpg

Comment: I do not recommand this, combo boxes are input elements i.e. elements that take input from user, what you want is to show information

Comment: you can put a row for every bank account the company has or show only the ids of bankaccounts in ordinary textbox

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a `CellFactory`, too: (exemplary)

```
ObservableList<BankAccount> bankValues = FXCollections.emptyList();
accountColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
                  new DefaultStringConverter(), bankValues));
```

Also, i think you need to remove the List from the column:

```
private TableColumn<ViewCompany, BankAccount> accountColumn;
```